# How do I add conditional browser classes in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, browser, cross-browser

I've noticed Wordpress sites that have classes in the `<html>` tag related to browser detection (if I use Firefox the html tag would have a .firefox class, even a version-detected .firefox16 class, and so on). Example, http://achristmasstorythemusical.com.
Is this a default Wordpress function like `body_class()` or do I have to create one? How would I do this?

Comment: Might be the Thematic theme framework; that does it, I think.

Comment: You're right. I noticed Thematic offers this functionality. Their function is in a file called dynamic-classes.php, unfortunately the way to add their functionality to a custom theme is complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I found no default Wordpress browser detection class nor function. [There are plugins that offer browser detection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-browser-detection/). However, I found a simple answer looking at the code snippet [here](http://snipplr.com/view/25531/). I just modified the code to return some basic browsers and added it to my functions.php file.

```
//return a conditional browser string
function browser_detect(){
    $iphone = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    $firefox = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Firefox");
    $safari = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Safari");
    $ie = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"MSIE");
    $opera = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Opera");
    $chrome = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Chrome");
    //detecting device 
    if ($iphone == true){
                echo "iphone";
    }
    elseif($firefox == true){
                echo "firefox";
    }
    elseif($ie == true){
                echo "explorer";
    }
    elseif($chrome == true){
                echo "chrome";
    }
    elseif($safari == true){
                echo "safari";
    }
    elseif($opera == true){
                echo "opera";
    }
    else{
        echo "unknown";
    }
};
```

Then, I added the function to my html tag.

```
<html class="<?php browser_detect(); ?>">
```

This will return the name of the browser I'm using as a class. For my immediate purpose, it's enough. I hope you find this answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). If you include that it injects those classes dependent on the ability of the browser, etc.

Comment: I didn't know Modernizr added classes to the markup. Anyway, the example site I provided doesn't even have Modernizr installed.

Comment: Looks like it's using some sort of php to do that then. However, that site is a really bad example. Look at all the JS errors!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how JavaScript errors have anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a Typekit plugin when you check the loaded scripts.

Comment: Can you refer a link to a plugin with that function? It may help.